# Magento 2 - Where is the template for sales/order/print/order_id/x

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I am searching the template for the order PDF which is showing in checkout success when you click the "print receipt" link.

Where can I find it? I have to change the header.

Comment: what you want to change?

Comment: Does not mather, maybe multiple things